# Php Convert to ISO-8859-9

Tags: php, json, utf-8, character-encoding

I use JSON to encode an array, and I get a string like this:

```
{"name":"\u00fe\u00fd\u00f0\u00f6\u00e7"}
```

Now I need to convert this to ISO-8859-9. I tried the following but it fails:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-9');
$json = json_encode($response);
$json = utf8_decode($json);
$json = mb_convert_encoding($json, "ISO-8859-9", "auto");
echo $json;
```

It doesnt seem to work. What am I missing?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: So your JSON data is in `$response`?

Comment: $response is an array having data which i do json_encode on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
$json = json_encode($response);
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-9');
echo mb_convert_encoding($json, "ISO-8859-9", "UTF-8");
```

Assuming that strings in `$response` is in utf-8. But I would strongly suggest that you just use utf-8 all the way through.

Edit: Sorry, just realised that won't work, since `json_encode` escapes unicode points as javascript escape codes. You'll have to convert these to utf-8 sequences first. I don't think there are any built-in functionality for that, but you can use a slightly modified variation of [this library](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/php-utf8/) to get there. Try the following:

```
function unicode_hex_to_utf8($hexcode) {
  $arr = array(hexdec(substr($hexcode[1], 0, 2)), hexdec(substr($hexcode[1], 2, 2)));
  $dest = '';
  foreach ($arr as $src) {
    if ($src < 0) {
      return false;
    } elseif ( $src <= 0x007f) {
      $dest .= chr($src);
    } elseif ($src <= 0x07ff) {
      $dest .= chr(0xc0 | ($src >> 6));
      $dest .= chr(0x80 | ($src & 0x003f));
    } elseif ($src == 0xFEFF) {
      // nop -- zap the BOM
    } elseif ($src >= 0xD800 && $src <= 0xDFFF) {
      // found a surrogate
      return false;
    } elseif ($src <= 0xffff) {
      $dest .= chr(0xe0 | ($src >> 12));
      $dest .= chr(0x80 | (($src >> 6) & 0x003f));
      $dest .= chr(0x80 | ($src & 0x003f));
    } elseif ($src <= 0x10ffff) {
      $dest .= chr(0xf0 | ($src >> 18));
      $dest .= chr(0x80 | (($src >> 12) & 0x3f));
      $dest .= chr(0x80 | (($src >> 6) & 0x3f));
      $dest .= chr(0x80 | ($src & 0x3f));
    } else {
      // out of range
      return false;
    }
  }
  return $dest;
}

print mb_convert_encoding(
  preg_replace_callback(
    "~\\\\u([1234567890abcdef]{4})~", 'unicode_hex_to_utf8',
    json_encode($response)),
  "ISO-8859-9", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I am getting an output like this now: �?�?�?�ö�ç"
Its close but not yet there? Please help.

Comment: How are you consuming the json?

Comment: Basically sending it to jQuery on an ajax call. The page has charset ISO-8859-9 encoding (unfortunately I cant control the page charset). My plugin basically adds on top of the site. How do I fix this mess?

Comment: If Javascript is consuming the data, you shouldn't change the charset. The encoding that the page is served in, doesn't affect Javascripts internal charset. Just send json data as unicode-escapes (the default behaviour of json_encode). To do so, you need to convert your php-strings to UTF-8, and then pass them to json_encode. That's all really.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on the [PHP documentation site](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) JSON encoding/decoding functions only work with utf8 encoding, so trying to change this can cause you some data problems, you may get unexpected and wrong results.

Comment: after i have the output from json (which is in utf8) can't i convert it to 'ISO-8859-9'?

Comment: yes, but the problem is after the conversion when you do a decode you can get wrong data.

If you don't need to do a decode, for example you read it in Javascript, you will get all the data correctly if you page is ISO